# Speed up grouping with `apply` on a single column

Tags: python, performance, pandas, numpy, pandas-groupby

I want to group a table such that the two first columns remain as they were when grouped, the 3d is the grouping mean, and the 4th the grouping dispersion, defined in the code. This is how I currently do it:

```
x = pd.DataFrame(np.array(((1,1,1,1),(1,1,10,2),(2,2,2,2),(2,2,8,3))))

   0  1   2  3
0  1  1   1  1
1  1  1  10  2
2  2  2   2  2
3  2  2   8  3

g      = x.groupby(0)
res    = g.mean()
res[3] = g.apply(lambda x: ((x[2]+x[3]).max()-(x[2]-x[3]).min())*0.5)
res

     1    2    3
0               
1  1.0  5.5  6.0
2  2.0  5.0  5.5
```

I am looking to speed this up anyway possible. In particular if I could get rid of `apply` and use `g` only once that would be great.

For testing purposes, this runs on data sizes of:

1. A few to 60 rows
2. 1-5 groups (there could be a single group)
3. 4 columns

Here is a mid-sized sample:

```
array([[  0.00000000e+000,   4.70221520e-003,   1.14943038e-003,
      3.44829114e-009],
   [  1.81557753e-011,   4.94065646e-324,   4.70221520e-003,
      1.14943038e-003],
   [  2.36416931e-008,   1.97231804e-011,   9.88131292e-324,
      8.43322640e-003],
   [  1.74911362e-003,   3.43575891e-009,   1.12130677e-010,
      1.48219694e-323],
   [  8.43322640e-003,   1.74911362e-003,   3.42014182e-009,
      1.11974506e-010],
   [  1.97626258e-323,   4.70221520e-003,   1.14943038e-003,
      3.48747627e-009],
   [  1.78945412e-011,   2.47032823e-323,   4.70221520e-003,
      1.14943038e-003],
   [  2.32498418e-008,   1.85476266e-010,   2.96439388e-323,
      4.70221520e-003],
   [  1.14943038e-003,   3.50053798e-009,   1.85476266e-011,
      3.45845952e-323],
   [  4.70221520e-003,   1.14943038e-003,   4.53241298e-008,
      3.00419304e-010],
   [  3.95252517e-323,   4.70221520e-003,   1.14943038e-003,
      3.55278482e-009],
   [  1.80251583e-011,   4.44659081e-323,   4.70221520e-003,
      1.14943038e-003],
   [  1.09587738e-008,   1.68496045e-011,   4.94065646e-323,
      4.70221520e-003],
   [  1.14943038e-003,   3.48747627e-009,   1.80251583e-011,
      5.43472210e-323],
   [  4.70221520e-003,   1.14943038e-003,   3.90545096e-008,
      2.63846519e-010],
   [  5.92878775e-323,   8.43322640e-003,   1.74911362e-003,
      3.15465136e-009],
   [  1.04009792e-010,   6.42285340e-323,   8.43322640e-003,
      1.74911362e-003],
   [  2.56120209e-010,   4.15414486e-011,   6.91691904e-323,
      8.43322640e-003],
   [  1.74911362e-003,   3.43575891e-009,   1.12286848e-010,
      7.41098469e-323],
   [  8.43322640e-003,   1.74911362e-003,   5.91887557e-009,
      1.45863583e-010],
   [  7.90505033e-323,   8.43322640e-003,   1.74911362e-003,
      3.34205639e-009],
   [  1.07133209e-010,   8.39911598e-323,   8.43322640e-003,
      1.74911362e-003],
   [  1.21188587e-009,   7.07453993e-011,   8.89318163e-323,
      8.43322640e-003],
   [  1.74911362e-003,   3.38890765e-009,   1.12130677e-010,
      9.38724727e-323],
   [  8.43322640e-003,   1.74911362e-003,   1.79596488e-009,
      8.38637515e-011]])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use syntacting sugar - `.groupby` with `Series`:

```
res[3] = ((x[2] + x[3]).groupby(x[0]).max() - (x[2] - x[3]).groupby(x[0]).min())*.5
print (res)
     1    2    3
0               
1  1.0  5.5  6.0
2  2.0  5.0  5.5
```

I get this timigs with you array:

```
In [279]: %%timeit
     ...: res    = x.groupby(0).mean()
     ...: res[3] = ((x[2] + x[3]).groupby(x[0]).max() - (x[2] - x[3]).groupby(x[0]).min())*.5
     ...: 
4.26 ms ± 62.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [280]: %%timeit
     ...: g      = x.groupby(0)
     ...: res    = g.mean()
     ...: res[3] = g.apply(lambda x: ((x[2]+x[3]).max()-(x[2]-x[3]).min())*0.5)
     ...: 
11 ms ± 76.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

---

Also if turn off sorting by grouping column if possible:

```
In [283]: %%timeit
     ...: res    = x.groupby(0, sort=False).mean()
     ...: res[3] = ((x[2] + x[3]).groupby(x[0], sort=False).max() - (x[2] - x[3]).groupby(x[0], sort=False).min())*.5
     ...: 
4.1 ms ± 50.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Comment: Isn't using `groupby` twice even more overhead than `apply`? I am not near a computer so I cannot time things.

Comment: Ok, and waht is number of groups? 4 only?

Comment: I started running it, and it feels faster. I will accept later in case there are other optimizations people think of (that `sort`ing thing was a good catch!)